# Match all characters up to a capture group, excluding the capture group

Tags: regex

I have a pattern

```
blah_blah_blah_blah_19292_blah_m32.jpg
```

I want to match everything up to _mXX while excluding the _mXX.

I have `^(.*[_m])` but this is inclusive.  Can't seem to get the capture group excluded.  What am I missing?

rubular link http://www.rubular.com/r/0Ls12Z6GH7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead for that:

```
/^.*?(?=_m[0-9]+)/
```

Will match `blah_blah_blah_blah_19292_blah` in your input string.

#### Online Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/abgW0Q1gjX

#### Referece: [Lookarounds in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Quoting from above link:

> `q(?=u)` matches a q that is followed by a u, without making the u part of the match. The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.

Comment: can you explain the ?= for me?  I was reading on lookaheads and could grasp what was happening very well

Comment: It's explained very well here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @BartEnkelaar: Thanks, incidentally that's the link I quoted in my answer as well.